# Is there a Matlab built in function that could give the indices of the free variables of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am taking Linear Algebra in college and I am trying to design a program in Matlab that could give me a the indices of the basic variables and the free variables of a certain matrix. The function `pivot` would give me the indices of the basic variables.

Is there a Matlab built in function that could give the indices of the free variables of a matrix?

Here's a sample of the function that I used to find the pivot:

```
[B,pivot] = rref(A)
```

Basically what this function `pivot` does is it stores the indices of basic variables of the matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `free_vars = setdiff(1:size(A,2),pivot)`. Example:

```
>> A = magic(4)

A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> [B, pivot] = rref(A)

B =

     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     3
     0     0     1    -3
     0     0     0     0


pivot =

     1     2     3

>> setdiff(1:4,pivot)

ans =

     4
```